# Referencing files inside a JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, structure

I am creating a Java app for some serial port communication and within the app's folder I have two resources that need to be present at run-time. The first is an image that is being used as a splash screen and the other is a configuration file that needs to be read as the program starts.

Here is an abridged version of the output from the "tree" command in Linux, the two files that I need to be referencing are "commandSet.config" and "splash-screen2.png"

```
.
├── bin
│   ├──...
├── commandSet.config
├── app-manifest.txt
├── splash-screen2.png
└── src
    ├── events
    │   └── InterfaceEvents.java
    ├── models
    │   ├── Command.java
    │   └── Phone.java
    ├── operations
    │   ├── Application.java
    │   ├── ...
    └── views
        ├── CallDialog.java
        ├── SplashScreen.java
        └── Window.java
```

I am currently referencing in the following lines:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("commandSet.config"));
```

and

```
JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("splash-screen2.png"));
```

This works fine when I am running it from Eclipse, but as soon as I export to a runnable JAR the files are not moved and therefore aren't correctly referenced. I have tried moving them into the "src" folder, which resulted in them being archived within the JAR, but I still couldn't reference them.

I'm pretty new to the concept of exporting Java projects, so maybe I have missed something obvious. If someone could show me the best way to do this and the best approach for future project file systems, I would be very grateful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I mananged to crack this and thought I'd drop an answer for others in the future. I basically followed "duffymo's" guidelines, here's what I did:

- Created a JAR with my resources in.
- Put that JAR in the **root** of the project.
- Used Eclipse to add that JAR to the build path.
- Used getResourceAsStream("*/nameOfFile.ext*") to get the streams for my resources.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
 InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("splash-screen2.png");  
byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(buffer);  
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(buffer);
```

Comment: This will return an inputStream though right? There's no constructor overload for ImageIcon that accepts an inputStream object as a parameter.

Comment: You need to load the contents of the InputStream into a byte[] array and use that constructor.

Comment: Using this method I get a NullPointer Exception,however, removing the leading / loads it correctly, the problem still exists when exporting to JAR.

Comment: write "splash-screen2.png" instead of "/splash-screen2.png". I change this in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't access that file the same way you would if it were in the file system.

Use `getResourceAsStream()` from your context to read it from the CLASSPATH using the class loader.

Comment: Ok, where about's should the files be stored to reference them in this way?

Comment: In the JAR or WAR that you deploy your app in, of course.  Since the class loader looks in the CLASSPATH, you'll need them to be in the CLASSPATH.  In your JAR, that's in the manifest Class-Path.  In your WAR, that's the WEB-INF/classes folder

Comment: Ok, for reference, I am only working with JARs. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by, "you'll need them to be in the CLASSPATH"? I have a manifest file, which contains the following: 


Main-Class: operations.Application